# Equivalent encryption logic in MySQL

Tags: mysql, encryption

[image]

What will be equivalent encryption logic in MySQL ?
Using something like following is not yielding require result.

select sha2('Tpostest123',256);

Comment: for the java code, please click on the link <enter image description here>

Comment: what result is it yielding?  it works for me.  what is your database version?

Comment: Following are the details: 
String Value: Tpostest123 
Encryption value as per java code: h4kYUPkRL5rFNVqe+B5HfZgkesgugn2OK0cMW+bfmfc= 
Encryption value in MySQL (select sha2('Tpostest123',256);): 87891850f9112f9ac5355a9ef81e477d98247ac82e827d8e2b470c5be6df99f7

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA2 returns a hexidecimal string value; you want it in base64 form instead.  For that, do:

```
select to_base64(unhex(sha2('Tpostest123',256)));
```